# TCP Server is overwhelmed by clients that only "connect" without sending any data

Tags: sockets, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener, denial-of-service

I have created a TCP server using .NET TcpListener.

I have some concerns on how it could be abused by spamming a lot of bogus connections similar to a DoS-like kind of attack.

I created a small console app to repeatedly initiate a connection to the server (only "connect" without transmitting other kind of data). The "max allowable concurrent connections limit" which is a setting in the server to prevent it from being overwhelmed, was met in an instant. This rendered my server pretty much useless since it could not accept new connections unless the other fake connections disconnect. This proves that my concern is not unfounded.

Is there any way we can do from the application level to prevent this?
I was thinking to require clients to send a kind of token when connecting and the server would refuse connections that don't but I don't think TCP works that way.

Is relying on external solutions the only way? Eg. VPN, firewall, NAT etc?

Comment: Please read [ask], share your research and ask a very specific question. Also provide more information about the nature of the service to narrow it down. For all we know, you only have one client you trust, and then you'd be helped by hiding the thing behind a VPN. Writing a proper, exhaustive answer to _"how to prevent an internet-connected service from being abused"_ would be way too long.

Comment: At the application level: If possible, use a secure-and-reliable-UDP library that does better than SYN cookies. Otherwise, at least implement a timeout to kill individual connections if no data has been received for 5 seconds.

Comment: If you want to mitigate this problem, you could decide on a maximum-simultaneous-connections limit; then keep a counter of how many connections you currently have open; when the counter reaches your threshold and another TCP connection comes in, select an existing TCP connection and close() it, thereby keeping the total connection count from exceeding your threshold.  (Try to choose the oldest existing connection that hasn't sent any data, though, so that the "bad" connections won't drive out the "good" ones)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I find them very insightful. Although not able to fully eradicate the problems, at least mitigation at the application level is a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a read timeout on every accepted socket, and close it if it triggers.